# Set a $_SESSION to redirect if not registered

Tags: php, session, redirect, header

I've currently setup a secure login script with the help of the internet, it's working... Almost.

I need it to re-direct to the login page index.php if the session isn't registered.

please see below code:

```
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user">
        <li class="dropdown user-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
            <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?><b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Inbox <span class="badge">7</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Settings</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="includes/logout.php"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

The current code, basically includes the username if logged in. However it does nothing else... and doesn't protect the page... any assistance would be appreciated...please note i'm very much a noob with php.

I'd like to just used a

header('Location: ../index.php')...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this test at the top of your code

```
<?php 
if(!login_check($mysqli))  {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use your `login_check()` on top of the page:

```
<?php 
if(login_check($mysqli) != true)  {
    header('Location: ...');
} elseif(login_check($mysqli) == true)  {
?>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user">
    <li class="dropdown user-dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
     <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?><b class="caret"></b></a>
<!-- rest of your html -->
<?php
} //closing elseif
?>
```